# Dapper data serialization problem on Dot Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, dapper

I have a strange error with Dapper (2.0.30) on new DotNet Core 3.0.

I am trying to load data from database with this command:

```
await connection.QueryAsync(command)).AsList()
```

And I want to return result as json

```
return this.Ok(Database.Load("SELECT * FROM table_name;"));
```

But I am getting this strange error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type '<GetEnumerator>d__9' to type 'System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator'.
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleDictionary(JsonClassInfo elementClassInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Int32 originalWriterDepth, Int32 flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore(Stream utf8Json, Object value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>g__Logged|21_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultFilters>g__Awaited|27_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I tried exact same code on DotNet 2.0 and it worked. I guess that it has something to do with new build in json serialize, that is not compatible with dapper or something?

I looked up on internet but I could not find much (nothing actually) about this. 
Just this quote from this [website](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/dotnet/corefx/41329/535272256)

> This looks like a bug in how we deal with types that implement
>   IDictionary where we expect such types to return an
>   enumerator that implements IDictionaryEnumerator (and types like
>   DapperRow don't implement that interface).

```
System.Text.Json.Serialization.Tests.ValueTests.DapperTest [FAIL]
        System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type '<GetEnumerator>d__9' to type 'System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator'.
        Stack Trace:
          E:\GitHub\Fork\corefx\src\System.Text.Json\src\System\Text\Json\Serialization\JsonSerializer.Write.HandleDictionary.cs(64,0): at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleDictionary(JsonClassInfo elementClassInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, WriteStack& state)
          E:\GitHub\Fork\corefx\src\System.Text.Json\src\System\Text\Json\Serialization\JsonSerializer.Write.cs(40,0): at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Int32 originalWriterDepth, Int32 flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
          E:\GitHub\Fork\corefx\src\System.Text.Json\src\System\Text\Json\Serialization\JsonSerializer.Write.Helpers.cs(131,0): at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object value, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
          E:\GitHub\Fork\corefx\src\System.Text.Json\src\System\Text\Json\Serialization\JsonSerializer.Write.Helpers.cs(107,0): at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore(PooledByteBufferWriter output, Object value, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
          E:\GitHub\Fork\corefx\src\System.Text.Json\src\System\Text\Json\Serialization\JsonSerializer.Write.Helpers.cs(86,0): at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCoreString(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
          E:\GitHub\Fork\corefx\src\System.Text.Json\src\System\Text\Json\Serialization\JsonSerializer.Write.String.cs(21,0): at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize[TValue](TValue value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
          E:\GitHub\Fork\corefx\src\System.Text.Json\tests\Serialization\Value.WriteTests.cs(47,0): at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Tests.ValueTests.DapperTest()
```

> Therefore, we are failing at this cast, since the enumerator that
>   DapperRow returns is IEnumerator> and not
>   IDictionaryEnumerator:
>   https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/b832f6ccdebd18469e4b6d03c1c9b2c9c6c14374/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Write.HandleDictionary.cs#L64

Does anyone knows how to make it work?
Thanks

**Update:**

I kinda fix it.

First I added libary from nudget **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.**
And added Newtonsoft as default json middleware.

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

And

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

But I still dont know why it did not run out of box, as it was on previous version of DotNet core.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the following documentation that describes how to migrate from Asp.net core 2.2 to version 3:

> The default JSON serializer for ASP.NET Core is now System.Text.Json,
>   which is new in .NET Core 3.0. Consider using System.Text.Json when
>   possible. It's high-performance and doesn't require an additional
>   library dependency. However, since System.Text.Json is new, it might
>   currently be missing features that your app needs

Maybe the new serializer doesn't support this feature yet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 3 the new `System.Text.Json` serialiser only supports dictionaries with strings as keys. If you want a dictionary with any other type you either need to [write a custom deserializer](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30524#issuecomment-524619972) or continue to use Newtonsoft JSON for now.

This is fixed in .NET 5's version: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/38056